# How to simplify the jQuery code in the example?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a plugin for loada pages of AJAX https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax
The problem is that it updates only one container on the page and need a few.
The following code works, but it is a deprecated (second container is updated with a delay). How can you optimize that containers loaded at the same time?

```
$(document).on("click", "a.item-link", (function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');
      $.pjax({
          url: thisUrl,
          container: '.pjax',
          fragment: '.pjax'
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $.pjax({
          url: thisUrl,
          container: '.box-mnu',
          fragment: '.box-mnu'
        });
      }, 1000);
  }));
```

Comment: why are you using a plugin for this just write it yourself with ajax

Comment: _"The following code works, but it is a deprecated (second container is updated with a delay). How can you optimize that containers loaded at the same time?"_ Remove `setTimeout` ?

Comment: Do you want them to load at the same time or to appear on the page at the same time? These are 2 different problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) , removing `setTimeout` call

```
  $(document).on("click", "a.item-link", (function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');
      $(".pjax").load(thisUrl);
      $(".box-mnu").load(thisUrl);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `setTimeout` call in the code.

```
$(document).on("click", "a.item-link", (function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      var thisUrl = $(this).attr('href');
      $.pjax({
         url: thisUrl,
         container: '.pjax',
         fragment: '.pjax'
      });
      $.pjax({
         url: thisUrl,
         container: '.box-mnu',
         fragment: '.box-mnu'
      });
}));
```